# Swift - is there a boolean convertible protocol or any other way to overload casting to a custom type?

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I created an enum which mimics a boolean, and I would like to be able to automatically cast real booleans to this custom type.

It's possible to do it for literal boolean thanks to the BooleanLiteralConvertible protocol (see below).

Is there an equivalent protocol for non literal boolean? Or is there a way to overload the as? operator ?

```
enum CustomType {
    case True
    case False
}
extension CustomType : BooleanLiteralConvertible {
    init(booleanLiteral value: BooleanLiteralType) {
        if value {
            self = .True
        } else {
            self = .False
        }
    }
}
func def(a: CustomType) {

}

func test() {
    let a : Bool = true
    def(true) // compiles
    def(a) // does not compile
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were features to support things like this in early versions of Swift and they were intentionally removed. Swift typically avoids implicit type conversions. They tend to explode compile times, and often lead to unexpected and undesired conversions. The current implicit conversion from `T` to `T?` is a common source of confusing compiler errors and incorrect overload calls in generic code. Building more things like that without many more changes to the Swift compiler is problematic. Even implicit numeric conversions, which the Swift team has expressed as desirable in principle, are not currently possible due to these problems and you need to explicitly convert.

The preferred way is to define an explicit overload in cases where it is useful:

```
func def(a: Bool) { def(CustomType(a)) }
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe protocol `BooleanType` can help you ,try to implement it like this:

```
enum CustomType :BooleanType{
var boolValue: Bool {
    switch self {
    case .True:
        return true
    case .False:
        return false
    }
}
    case True
    case False
    init(bool:Bool){
        self = bool ? .True : .False
    }

}
```

then you can use :

```
let myTrue = true
let trueType = CustomType(bool: myTrue)

if trueType {
    print("hello world")
}
```

note: `LiteralConvertible` protocols are only made for Literal conversion

Comment: I'd like to avoid the CustomType(bool: myTrue). I want to be able to do: def(a) with b boolean

Comment: I think your note is wrong. I can do def(true) as defined above thank to LiteralConvertible

Comment: @BaptisteTruchot yes ,but LiteralConvertible can't do something like cast

Comment: hum ok so I guess my question is badly phrased. So you think there is no way to achieve what I was looking for ? ie. passing another type to a function

Comment: @BaptisteTruchot yes , i think LiteralConvertible can't achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a `struct` instead of an `enum` and using some static constants to make them work "like" enums

```
struct CustomType : BooleanType {

    private let bValue : Bool

    var boolValue: Bool { return bValue }

    init(bool: Bool) {

        self.bValue = bool
    }
}

extension CustomType {

    static let False = CustomType(bool: false)

    static let True = CustomType(bool: true)
}

extension CustomType : BooleanLiteralConvertible {

    init(booleanLiteral value: BooleanLiteralType) {

        self = CustomType(bool: value)
    }
}
```

And you can use them by doing

```
let myType : CustomType = .False
```

as an enum (even if they are absolutely not the same)